# PayPal Developer my apps - how to remove them?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

On my PayPal Developer account, under Applications, My apps, I created a REST API app.

I don't need it anymore and want to delete it, but just cannot find the right place to do so. Is deletion not allowed?

Comment: I too am looking for an answer to this question. I searched all documentation I can find in developer.paypal.com and couldn't find anything.

Comment: did they actualy forget to allow app deletion? Seems the new app systems mightn't be ready yet. Might stick to the classic apps: https://apps.paypal.com/

Comment: thats , what i am searching .

Comment: Just retire it, it has an option to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete App facility is now added in PayPal.

1. Goto developer.paypal.com
2. Click **My Apps**
3. You will get all applications list
4. Then look at right side of each application there you will get the "**Delete**" button.
5. Clicking it will pops an window
6. Write your application name in text box and click delete.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

At this time you can't.
The only thing that you can do is retire an application. Once you retire it, its API credentials become invalid, and the name is displayed as

*your app name* [RETIRED]

Comment: How can I retire the application? I don't see any button nor link to do this.

Comment: Why the downvote???
I'm just letting you know the current state of affairs.

Don't shoot the messenger :P